# how to make better synchronization between views and data

Tags: android

Imagine there is a `MainActivity` in which there is a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`. In the views that belong to the `MainActivity` I update the data directly; for example, in my `PageAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) arg0;
    if (vp.getCurrentItem() != this.current_item){
        this.current_item = vp.getCurrentItem();
        ContentStatus status;
        switch(vp.getCurrentItem()){
        case(0): 
            status = ContentStatus.NOTINTERESTING;
            break;
        case(2): 
            status = ContentStatus.INTERESTING;
            break;
        default: 
            status = ContentStatus.ACTIVE;
        }
        MainActivity.content.setItemStatus(content.identifier, status);
        final Activity act = (Activity) this.context;
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) ((ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.view_sequence)).getAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I need to reproduce this code in another activity which opens from the `MainActivity` and uses the same data, because if the user changes some data from the other activity and then closes it and returns to the MainActivity I must redraw `MainActivity`'s views. As a variant, should I use `Activity`'s `onResume()` method to update all views that haves bindings to data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I use activitie's onResume method to update all views that haves bindings to data?

Short answer? Yes - if your activity's view state might change every time the activity is paused and resumed, then it makes sense to update them all on a resume.  This is more in line with the 'android way' if you will - two activities should not affect each other unless they are somehow working with the same data.  If they are working with the same data, You might consider making your second activity a [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead; that way all operations related to that bit of data are tied to a single activity with multiple fragments.

Comment: Yup. Keep most logic in the fragments and tell the fragments to resume themselves in onResume().

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to tell the adapter that the data changed, when back in the first activity, this way views will be refreshed. So in your `MainActivity` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ((AdapterYouAreUsing) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Assuming your are starting your 2nd activity with the `startActivityForResult()` method. Or you will have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onResume()` one.